# Search in an onion of class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Given an integer template parameter `Key`, the search method should extract a layer of the onion that has `key == Key` during compilation.

How to fix the search method?

Test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aclass+A+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++static+constexpr+int+key+%3D+0%3B%0A++++template%3Cint+s%3E%0A++++constexpr+auto%26+search()+const+%7B+return+*this%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+P%3E%0Aclass+B+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++static+constexpr+int+key+%3D+P::key+%2B+1%3B%0A++++template+%3Cint+Key%3E%0A++++constexpr+auto%26+search()+const+%7B%0A++++++++if+constexpr+(Key+%3D%3D+key)+return+*this%3B%0A++++++++return+p_.search%3CKey%3E()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++P+p_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++B%3CB%3CB%3CB%3CA%3E%3E%3E%3E+onion%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+onion.search%3C1%3E().key+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.154046997389045,l:'4',m:71.89249720044792,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3+',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:48.99103139013454,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+5.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:51.00896860986548,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.84595300261096,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    static constexpr int key = 0;
    template<int s>
    constexpr auto& search() const { return *this; }
};

template<class P>
class B {
public:
    static constexpr int key = P::key + 1;
    template <int Key>
    constexpr auto& search() const {
        if constexpr (Key == key) return *this;
        return p_.search<Key>();
    }
    P p_;
};

int main() {
    B<B<B<B<A>>>> onion;
    std::cout << onion.search<1>().key << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
         return p_.search<Key>();
                               ^
```

Comment: A search that only works for `D<C<B<A>>>`, `C<D<B<A>>>`, and other permutations of `BCD` would be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`template` disambiguator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_template_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) for dependent name:

```
constexpr auto& search() const {
    if constexpr (Key == key) {
        return *this;
    } else {
        return p_.template search<Key>();
                  ^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rzu I thought it was your typo... But I already fixed it in my answer.

Comment: @Swift You are confused with `if` and `if constexpr`, `if constexpr` will only choose the correct branch to compile. No other problem here.

Comment: @ liliscent my bad.. I'm not used to compilers that support that. I always wonder though why if can't be deduced to be `constexpr` if expression in it is  `constexpr`.

Comment: Ha. it seems to work. Thanks.